# Flex basis no funciona correctamente en internet explorer 11

Tags: css

Tengo un grid de 4 items con ayuda de esta regla

```
.flex__item{
    flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

No funciona en internet explorer 11, el cuarto item se va abajo y no se queda en la misma linea que los tres primeros items.

Hay algun polyfill o algo que pueda hacer?

En google chrome se muestra bien, en fila de 4

Comment: Yo no me preocuparía demasiado por hacer que todo funcione bien en Internet Explorer a no ser que sea estrictamente necesario. Porque es un navegador obsoleto y quienes lo siguen usando ya deben estar acostumbrados a que las páginas que visitan no funcionen bien.

Comment: Lo se, pero es un requerimiento que pide el cliente u.u

Comment: Bienvenido a Internet Explorer :3

Answer (score 1):

flex no funciona igual en esa versión de IE. En general hay tantas situaciones de este tipo, que existe una página para checar que sí y que no funciona en cada navegador. Aquí el link con respecto a flex: https://caniuse.com/flexbox

Si te diriges a la pestaña de "known issues" verás que entre los varios problemas, está:

```
In IE10 the default value for flex is 0 0 auto rather 
than 0 1 auto as defined in the latest spec.
```

En tu caso, intenta separar la instruccion de flex y sus atributos, por ejemplo:

```
.flex__item{
    -ms-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Y después agregas los otros atributos de dimensiones en otra linea.